# Getting objects in linked lists vs. arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, linked-list

Ok so this is probably a very beginner question but...

Right now I have an object called Person with a method on it called setName

I am in my main class and I have declared

```
List People = new LinkedList();
```

What I want to do is simply call the setName function of the object in the first position.
I have found that this is very easy to do when working with an array of People. All I would do would be to say

```
People[0].setName("steve");
```

But since it is in a linkedlist I am having troubles.

I tried using the "get" method like so...

```
People.get(0)
```

but then it doesn't allow me to use my user defined methods so I can't set the name.

What is the best way to get an object out of a linked list and access its methods and instance variables?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use generics to make it a list of people:

```
List<Person> People = new LinkedList<Person>();

People.get(0).setName("steve");
```

Comment: Confusing names but ... yes, generics are the ticket.

Answer (score 4):

Use [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html):

```
List<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();
// …
people.get(0).setName("steve");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use generics: `List<Person>`. Then you would be able to use `people.get(0).setName(..)`

Note that Java naming convention requires your variable to be lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

You dont set which type of objects you store. So you need upcast:

```
Person person = (Person)People.get(0);
person.setName("steve");
```

or set type of stored objects:

```
List<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();
```

Answer (score 2):

[LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is only good when you want to iterate quickly over the list, and when you want to quickly get to the first or last element. Also, you need to properly define `people` as a `LinkedList` to have access to the linked list methods, and you should type your list, so:

```
LinkedList<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();
people.getFirst().setName();
```

However, `ArrayList` is a better general choice, which offers good performance when accessing elements by their index, so:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

then

```
people.get(0).setName("fred");
```

Comment: LinkedList is also faster at inserting and deleting elements in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If using Java 1.4 or earlier you need to cast it to People class:

```
((Person)People.get(0)).setName("SomeName");
```

If using Java 1.5 or later use generics:

```
List<Person> people = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Um, don't you mean `List<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();` for the generics version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Linked list as a Person LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();
people.get(0).setName("Steve");
```

Another note(not about the question, just to improve your Java): You use lowercase on the first letter of variable names, because of Java conventions and any subsequent word's first letter are capitalized;

```
float personsAge = 57.47;
```

EXPLANATION(Ignore if easily bored):

The LinkedList was not set to store a specific variable type.
Another way to have solved this problem would have been:

```
LinkedList people = new LinkedList();
Person person = (Person) people.get(0);
person.setName("steve2")
```

Although you would have to do this to each 'Person' in the people list, defeating the point of the LinkedList.